# Is there a way to link two Ethernet adapters in Windows so that they can share the same IP address?

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, ethernet, hyper-v, esxi

I just bought an Intel NUC running Windows 10 and it comes with a WiFi adapter as well as a wired Ethernet port.  I’m using my router to assign IP addresses based upon a device’s MAC address so they always get the same IP. I plan on using the Ethernet port, but every now and then I might move the machine to a location that doesn’t have a jack available.

I’d like to be able to use the WiFi, but still be able to use the IP address assigned to the wired port.  So if I have the following:

- Wired Ethernet 172.16.68.67
- WiFi Adapter   172.16.68.68

I’d like to always be able to use 172.16.68.67 as long as either the Ethernet is plugged in and/or the WiFi is connected.  Or even better, use 172.16.68.69 and the OS forwards traffic to 67 if it is connected, 68 if it is not.

One caveat is that I need to expose this adapter to HyperV so my virtual machines can use this adapter for connectivity.

Comment: If you only ever connect one or the other, you should be able to just set the same static IP on both interfaces.

Comment: WiFi and Ethernet cannot be bridged. If you want a static IP address, why not use a *static* address? Also, you cannot easily use a WiFi connection with Hyper-V, for the same reason.

Comment: Actually l *can* use the WiFi adapter with HyperV, but for some reason I can’t get the WiFi to connect upon boot.

Comment: Regarding the titular question, using two NICs for a given IP is called *Teaming*. It is often used for redundancy to improve uptime. In the old dialup modem days there was also something called *Shotgunning*, where two modems were paired and doubled the download speed. I don't think Windows allows either of them out of the box. You probably need to get custom drivers from the NIC manufacturer.

Comment: Regarding the way you want to use 172.16.68.67 and 172.16.68.68, I believe you accomplish that with static routes and cost assigned to the route. Your 172.16.68.67 route should have a lower cost than other routes.

Answer (score -1):

If you are familiar with scripting, you could do this fairly easily with Powershell.  Here is a guide on using the [New-NetIPaddress](https://www.howtogeek.com/112660/how-to-change-your-ip-address-using-powershell/) command you would use.  You could make it a startup script, and/or run it in intervals in the background.  Honestly, there are many ways you could trigger it.  Just script it based on your needs.

Comment: lol, another random downvote with no explanation.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I think the reason may be your answer is even less detailed than [this](https://i.imgur.com/Nt4jm.jpg).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski SuperUser is *not* a script writing service.  I offered the tool and direction he can use to successfully perform the task he requested.  Anything beyond that is outside the scope of the site.

Comment: @Keltari, I appreciate the suggestion.  I assume there is a PS command to connect to a SSID, which might accomplish what I need to do.  Do you know if it’s possible to start a script on machine boot instead of login?  Not sure if W10 can do this, but Server might,  I’m not a fan of relying on auto login and startup scripts.